# Trying to build a metronome in kivy - Event loop management

Tags: python, events, loops, kivy

since I haven't found anything here, I try and put my Question.

I'm trying to build a simple metronome in kivy. I basically took the Audio example which was provided with the installation und wanted to add a metronome functionality.

```
class AudioButton(ToggleButton):

    filename = StringProperty(None)
    sound = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_filename(self, instance, value):
        # the first time that the filename is set, we are loading the sample
        if self.sound is None:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load(value)

    def on_press(self):
        # stop the sound if it's currently playing
        if self.sound.status != 'stop':
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound.play()
```

As you can see, I changed the class from `Button` to `ToggleButton`.

I tried to put a `while` loop with the `self.sound.play()`, but that results in infinity, so basically I'm looking for a way to break out of the loop, if I press the Button again.

I didn't really understand the Event loop management from the documentation, which I think should be the answer, but I never used an event loop before.
It would be great if someone could provide some example code for such a situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place that you want to start looking is in the Kivy docs discussing [clock events](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#clock-events). In event-driven systems like this any kind of `while` loop takes the system to its knees. Instead, when you want something to happen periodically, you ask the system to set up a timer and tell it the function that you'd like to have called every time that timer elapses.

In your case, you'd probably just play that single metronome tick and be done until the next time the timer elapses.

Comment: Alright, I got it working, but now I can't quit it...the Buttonstate is always 'normal'. I call the clock event from inside the on_press function-help? ;)

Comment: You can either set the clock event on on_press, and remove it on on_release, or set it at the beginning of the program, and check the state of the button everytime, anyway, you probably want something a bit more complex than that, because most metronomes can change tempo, so you'll want to call your Clock event every frame, check both if the button is down and if the next tick has to happen, if yes, do the sound and compute time of next tick, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't think of the Clock event. My Metronome takes it's speed from somwhere else, so a tempochange results in a stop anyway ;)

Comment: Could you explain how to use the clock events info you mentioned to build a metronome?  I'm afraid I'm still lost even after reading that, and a metronome seems like a fairly fundamental kind of thing to implement.